# Can the Area and Views folders in ASP.Net MVC inherit data from the root web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

In an ASP.Net MVC app there is a web.config in the root directory, the views folder, and the area folder. I have declared a namespace in my root web.config but any views in the views or area folder are not picking it up unless I add it to that fold's respective web.config file. Is there a way to enable inheritance from the root to sub folder web.configs so what ever settings I place in the root web.config are seen in both the area and view folders?

Root Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>

    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>

    <httpModules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Views Folder web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: What syntax are you using to add the namespaces?

Comment: <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" /> as a sub of system.web ^> Pages -> namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the code given by Andrew Barber I had to add

```
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
```